# Usar window.location.href com variável AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Olá sou novo em angularjs,agradeço toda ajuda se puderem. tenho uma dúvida:
Tenho uma coleção de itens que são carregados na página principal está tudo ok ,mas um dos items é uma url e eu gostaria que quando carregado permitisse acessar a página de destino. Na realidade quando eu coloco a url diretamente na função funciona, mas tentando pegar de uma variável ,eu clico e não acontece nada .. o código abaixo funciona ***só essa primeira parte .

```
  var data = {};
  var app = angular.module('myApp',['onsen']);
   module.controller('myCtrl',function($window, $scope){
    $scope.myFunction = function(){
    $window.location.href =   ' **colocando o caminho de uma pagina aqui funciona, mas quero pegar da variavel myurl abaixo.**'


    }
});
```

O código quase completo abaixo.. JS  e html ..

```
module.factory('$data', function() {


  data.items = [
      {
          Image: 'steak-353115_640.jpg',
          title: 'Novo',
          label: 'Evento',
          desc: 'Gerencie um novo evento e .....,
          myurl: 'home.html'
      },
      {   Image: 'r878.jpg',
          title: 'Lista',
          label: 'Assistente',
          desc: 'Não definido',
           myurl: 'guia.html'
      }
  ];

  return data;
 });
var data = {};
  var app = angular.module('myApp',['onsen']);
   module.controller('myCtrl',function($window, $scope){
    $scope.myFunction = function(){
    $window.location.href =   myurl //Eu queria pegar a url da variável
    }
   });
```

A medida que eu clico em um item ele carrega os respectivos valores das variáveis, ou seja ,nuncarepete já que os dados são únicos

```
<ons-list modifier="inset" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <ons-list-item class="item">
                <ons-row>
                    <ons-col width="60px">
                        <div ><img class="item-thum" ng-src="images/{{item.Image}}" style="margin:auto;"></div>
                    </ons-col>
                    <ons-col>
                        <header>
                            <span class="item-title">{{item.title}}</span>
                            <span class="item-label">{{item.label}}</span>
                        </header>
                        <p class="item-desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
                    </ons-col>
                </ons-row>
            </ons-list-item>
           <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click="myFunction()">
                <ons-icon icon="ion-chatboxes" fixed-width="true" style="color: #ccc"></ons-icon>
                Add a note
            </ons-list-item>
```

Comment: Consegue imprimir os valores que estão sendo preenchidos na url?

Comment: se eu fizer assim : ' {{item.myurl}}'  carrego os dados ,mas não consigo navegar, aliás nem sei como  fazer.

Comment: Passe ela por parâmetro: `myFunction(item.myurl)`. Modifique seu método para usar a URL passada por parâmetro.

Comment: Tentei assim ,mas nada    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click= "myFunction(item.myurl)">

Comment: O que seria o ons-list e ons-list-item?

Comment: onsen ui ( framework)

Comment: segue os arquivos se alguem puder me dar uma dica, alem das que ja recebi (obrigado) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103204235/teste%20angularj.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim no teu controller:

```
module.controller('myCtrl',function($window, $scope){
       $scope.myFunction = function(item){
            var url = String(window.location);
            url = url.substr(0, String($window.location.href).indexOf("www") + 4);
            $window.location.href =  url + item.mmyurl;

       }
 });
```

E no HTML:

```
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click= "myFunction(item)">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-chatboxes" fixed-width="true" style="color: #ccc"></ons-icon>
      NAVEGAR PARA A PRÓXIMA PAGINA DE ACORDO COM OS ELEMENTOS CARREGADOS
</ons-list-item>
```

Comment: Cara tu é um gênio, podem contratar gente valeu demaissssss

Comment: Vlw precisando da um toque

Comment: Com certeza ..  salvando o link do seu profile!